# Doctrine persisting an array into an entity

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am pulling some data from an API and this is set in an array like such:

```
array (size=8)
  'name' => string 'Application Name' 
  'description' => string 'Application Description'
  'author' => string 'Author name'
  'version' => string '1.0.0' 
  'ip' => string '127.1.1' 
  'host' => string 'http://www.host.com'
  'image' => string 'http://www.hostc.com/image.png'
  'route' => 
    array 
      1 => 
        array 
          'name' => string 'route'
          'description' => string 'The description of route'
          'route' => string 'http://www.myroute.com/route'
      2 => 
        array 
          'name' => string 'route'
          'description' => string 'The description of route'
          'route' => string 'http://www.myroute.com/route'
      3 => 
        'name' => string 'route'
          'description' => string 'The description of route'
          'route' => string 'http://www.myroute.com/route'
```

This array reflects my Application Entity and its OneToMany join to the ApplicationRoute entity.

My question is this. is there a simple way to convert this into a usable object and to persist using Doctrine?

EDIT

A working solution that I have was to do this:

I created a function in my Application entity called: fromArray

```
public function fromArray($array)
{
    $this->setName($array['name']);
    $this->setDescription($array['description']);
    $this->setAuthor($array['author']);
    $this->setIp($array['ip']);
    $this->setHost($array['host']);
    $this->setImageUrl($array['image']);

    $routeCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    foreach ( $array['route'] AS $route) {
        $routeObejct = new ApplicationRoutes();
        $routeObejct->setName($route['name']);
        $routeObejct->setDescription($route['description']);
        $routeObejct->setRoute($route['route']);
        $routeCollection[] = $routeObejct;
    }

    $this->setRoute($routeCollection);

    return $this;
}
```

This does the job, I however feel there is a better way...

Any advice, much appreciated!

Comment: Do you not already have a hydrator that you use with your forms? A DoctrineObject hydrator perhaps? These can be used independently to hydrate/extract data to/from an object.

Comment: Well, my forms generally use these: DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject;